# Retrieve the match id under the cursor, in all cases

Tags: syntax-highlighting

How can I retrieve the syntax id under the cursor, in *all* cases?

Indeed, the `synID()` function doesn't take into account highlightings due to the `:match*` commands or the `matchadd()` function.

Example, in a C source file:

```c
void myfunc(char c)
{ }
```

Let's say I run in Vim:

```
:call matchadd('SpecialKey', '\<myfunc\>')
```

Then, when the cursor is on the word `char`:

```
:echo synID(line('.'), col('.'), 1)
235
```

But when the cursor is on the word `myfunc`:

```
:echo synID(line('.'), col('.'), 1)
0
```

Comment: That is not possible, because `matches` are totally different then syntax items. To retrieve the active matches, use the `getmatches()` function.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt : but `getmatches()` gives only infos about the match definition, not about the actual matches

Comment: What do you mean with `about the actual matches`? I fail to see what is missing

Comment: I mean: with infos given by `getmatches()`, it's impossible to retrieve the syntax group which is under the cursor. To follow the example in my question., when i'm on the word `myfunc`, i need to retrieve the name `SpecialKey`, or its id (which is `1` on my vim)

Comment: And by the return value of getmatches() you know, whether it would match `myfunc` and you know to which highlighting group it belongs. I still don't see the problem

Comment: To summarize, I need to retrieve (inside a script) the highlight group which is displayed under the cursor, even when the highlight comes from a `matchadd()` call. Sorry for mistakes, or bad english.

Comment: You wrote: "you know, whether it would match `myfunc`" but *no*, I can't easily check this; but more important: what I need is to find *which one*  in the list given by `getmatches()` is used under the cursor

Comment: I see now what you want. Something like 2html plugin. Unfortunately it is not currently possible to get that information in an easy way.

Answer (score 0):

`getmatches()` provides the match info including the pattern and match id. Run the patterns on the current line and check if cursor position is included in the match locations.