# Toggle specific highlight group

Tags: syntax-highlighting, highlight, conceal

Is it possible to temporarily disable the text highlight under cursor?

The current highlight group can be obtained by `synIDattr(synIDtrans(synID(line('.'), col('.'), 1)), 'name')`. How to clear it to restore it later? One approach can be to save the match-pattern used for the highlight (obtain how?) and then clear the highlight group. While restoring the highlight, enable the cleared highlight group on the stored match-pattern.

#### Background

I want to reveal the concealed text around the cursor. On every `CursorMoved` event, I will locate the surrounding concealed text, store enough highlight info to re-conceal in future and clear the conceal-highlight (preferably clear only for the text under cursor).

Comment: Maybe better to toggle conceallevel? Or set concealcursor (? I forget the exact option) to not conceal in (for example) visual mode?

Comment: Dup: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/11368/33130

Answer (score 0):

`getmatches()` provides the match info including the pattern and match id. If the cursor location is included in the pattern match delete it using `matchdelete()`.